# Sort a dictionary by key, value (tuple)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary with entries that are of the format:

`{...'key': ('value', '##')...}` where `##` is an integer.

Right now I want to sort and print by key, and then sort and print by value, and then finally sort and print by the number ##. I have looked around SO and have found and tried code that are similar to this:

`print(sorted(aDictionary))`

But this only prints out the keys of each entry (but it *is* sorted). How can I sort by key, value, then ##?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using custom comparators:

```
key1 = lambda (key, (value, hash)): key
key2 = lambda (key, (value, hash)): value
key3 = lambda (key, (value, hash)): hash
```

Use it like:

```
print(sorted(aDictionary.items(), key=key1))
```

BTW the above relies on [tuple unpacking in function parameters](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/); you could rephrase it for python 3 like:

```
key1 = lambda item: item[0][0]
key2 = lambda item: item[1][0]
key3 = lambda item: item[1][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the items instead of the keys (which is the default when iterating):

```
print(sorted(x.iteritems()))
```

You might also be interested in the OrderedDict: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

In this case the default sort will probably work, but you might need a custom `key` method:

```
key = lambda (k, (v0, v1)): (k, v0, v1)
sorted(x.iteritems(), key=key)
```